# where does django install in ubuntu

Tags: python, django, ubuntu

I am looking for the **init**.py file for django. I tried whereis and find, but I get a lot of dirs.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

you can just print it out.

```
>>> import django
>>> print django.__file__
/var/lib/python-support/python2.5/django/__init__.pyc
>>>
```

or:

```
import inspect
import django
print inspect.getabsfile(django)
```

Comment: Great tipp! Very usefull for all other libraries

Answer (score 4):

This (or something like this) also works when you are searching for files in other packages:

```
$ dpkg -L python-django | grep __init__.py
```

Answer (score 4):

Its now at

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/....
```

circa 2012

Answer (score 1):

A one-liner command (which is given in the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial07/#customizing-your-project-s-templates)) to find where your django source files are:

```
$ python -c "import django; print(django.__path__)"
```